# Nullpointer exception is thrown while using getResultList() method in Kundera

Tags: java, jpa, hbase, kundera

I am using Kundera as JPA with HBase and java. Following is the method which call getResultList() method:

```
 @Override
    public List<Activity> getAllActivities()
    {
        em = emf.createEntityManager();        
        Query q = em.createQuery("select ac from Activity ac");
        List<Activity> activities = q.getResultList();
        return activities;
    }
```

It throws nullpointer exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.impetus.kundera.index.IndexManager.search(IndexManager.java:191)
    at com.impetus.kundera.query.LuceneQuery.getResultList(LuceneQuery.java:101)
    at com.impetus.activity.dao.ActivityService.getAllActivities(ActivityService.java:100)
    at ActivityExample.main(ActivityExample.java:44)
```

P.S : Activity table in HBase has 6 records.
What can be the reason for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to add a property mentioned below

```
<property name="index_home_dir" value="./lucene" />
```

in persistence.xml.

Reason is your there is no default indexing support available with HBase.

It should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems, that `at com.impetus.kundera.index.IndexManager.search([IndexManager.java][1]:191)` there is a snippet:

```
public final Map<String, String> search(String query, int start, int count)
{
    return indexer.search(query, start, count, false); //line 191 
}
```

And indexer appears to be null. Indexer is passed as a parameter to IndexManager. Look for instantiation of indexer in your application.